# RE: callback function in Lua

Tags: lua

I am a beginner in LUA (2 days old). I have a function to be implemented whose defination in the user guide is as follows

```
mqtt_id = mqtt.create(config)

config: Lua table containing mqtt client connection parameters
“host” MQTT broker domain or IP address
“port” optional; MQTT broker connection port; default: 1883
“user” optional; user name
“onmessage” optional; Lua callback function to be executed on new message
                      function cb_func(len, topic, msg)
```

and there are some other values in the table also but are optional

I want to create a callback function and this is what I did in the declaration of `mqtt.create()` function

I add the complete code here

```
function sleep (a) 
    local sec = tonumber(os.clock() + a); 
    while (os.clock() < sec) do 
    end 
end

function cb_func(len, topic, msg)
    print('in on message')
    print(msg)
end

sleep(10000)

--configure GPRS APN 
sms_apn = net.setapn({apn = "airtelgprs.com"})
if sms_apn == 0 then
    print('gprs enabled')
else
    print('gprs not enabled')
    while true do
    end
end

--creating new mqtt client connections
mqtt_id = mqtt.create({host = "abc.xyz.com", port = 1883, qos = 2, onmessage = cb_func})
if mqtt_id ~= nil then
    print('configuring mqtt clint completed')
else
    print('configuring mqtt clint failed')
    while true do
    end
end

--connect to mqtt broker
status = mqtt.connect(mqtt_id,5,600)
if status == 0 then
    print('connected to mqtt broker')
else
    print('coonnection failed with mqtt broker')
    while true do
    end
end

--adding topic
mqtt.addtopic(mqtt_id, "Osm1", 2)
mqtt.addtopic(mqtt_id, "GW", 2)

--subscribing to the topics
mqtt.subscribe(mqtt_id)

mqtt.publish(mqtt_id, "GW", "ACTIVE")

while true do
    -- print('in infinite loop')

    --active
    --mqtt.publish(mqtt_id, "GW", "ACTIVE")
    --sleep(10000)

end
```

Am I doing it right? please help

the print message never happens in the callback function

Comment: `function onmessage_cb_func(length, topic, message) ` It is defined as you can see it below

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Can you please correct/provide an example?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Can you please check the code. I have edited my post

Comment: You'll know if you're doing it right if the code does what is supposed to do. Your definition of cb_func is ok.

Comment: Your function `cb_func` is OK.  The mistake is in the line `sleep(10000)`.  Why are you waiting for 10000 seconds?

Comment: Actually that sleep function is not for a second  am running it o a differenty processor so please Ignore

Comment: Commented out 'sleep' still it does not work

Comment: Can someone please help me with this issue

Comment: Anyone out there who can shed some light on this issue

Comment: What debugging displays do you see, such as `connected to mqtt broker`?

Comment: Yes, we are successfully able to send the data to the broker but while receiving the callback function never gets hit